# Unfortunately App has stopped working? VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio

In my app I want to add Facebook SDK. I was following a tutorial after that app has stopped.

Here is my code:
AndroidFacebookActivity

```
public class AndroidFacebookActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

Login Fragment:

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {
private CallbackManager callbackManager=null;
private AccessTokenTracker mtracker=null;
private ProfileTracker mprofileTracker=null;
public static final String PARCEL_KEY="parcel_key";
private LoginButton loginButton;

FacebookCallback<LoginResult> callback=new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        Profile profile=Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        homeFragment(profile);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException error) {

    }
};




@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    mtracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldAccessToken, AccessToken currentAccessToken) {

            Log.v("AccessTokenTracker", "oldAccessToken=" + oldAccessToken + "||" + "CurrentAccessToken" + currentAccessToken);
        }
    };
    mprofileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile currentProfile) {

            Log.v("Session Tracker", "oldProfile=" + oldProfile + "||" + "currentProfile" + currentProfile);
            homeFragment(currentProfile);

        }
    };
    mtracker.startTracking();
    mprofileTracker.startTracking();
}
private void homeFragment(Profile profile) {

    if (profile != null) {
        Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
        mBundle.putParcelable(PARCEL_KEY, profile);
        HomeFragment hf = new HomeFragment();
        hf.setArguments(mBundle);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainContainer, new HomeFragment());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
    // If using in a fragment
    loginButton.setFragment(this);
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, callback);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mtracker.stopTracking();
    mprofileTracker.stopTracking();
}


public boolean isLoggedIn() {
    AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
    return accessToken != null;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (isLoggedIn()) {
        loginButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        homeFragment(profile);
    }

}
}
```

HomeFragment:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
private ImageView profile_pic = null;
private TextView tv = null;
private Button logoutButton = null;
private Profile profile = null;



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    profile_pic = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
    tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
    logoutButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.logout_button);
    return view;
}
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();

    if (bundle != null) {
        profile = (Profile) bundle.getParcelable(LoginFragment.PARCEL_KEY);
    } else {
        profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
    }


    tv.setText("Welcome \n" + profile.getName());

    Picasso.with(getActivity())
            .load(profile.getProfilePictureUri(400, 400).toString())
            .into(profile_pic);

    logoutButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            logout();
        }
    });

}
private void logout() {
    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainContainer, new LoginFragment());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}


}
```

Manifest.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicatioId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"></meta-data>
    <activity android:name=".AndroidFacebookActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

</application>
```

and Here is my Log Cat

```
04-18 23:20:55.898 25376-25376/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
04-18 23:20:56.538 25376-25376/com.example.bebo.facebook W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
04-18 23:20:56.548 25376-25376/com.example.bebo.facebook I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
04-18 23:20:56.558 25376-25376/com.example.bebo.facebook W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 15210: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
04-18 23:20:56.568 25376-25376/com.example.bebo.facebook D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
04-18 23:20:56.568 25376-25376/com.example.bebo.facebook I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
04-18 23:20:56.568 25376-25376/com.example.bebo.facebook W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 15214: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
04-18 23:20:56.568 25376-25376/com.example.bebo.facebook D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
04-18 23:20:56.828 25376-25376/com.example.bebo.facebook I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
04-18 23:20:56.858 25376-25376/com.example.bebo.facebook W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 464: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
04-18 23:20:56.858 25376-25376/com.example.bebo.facebook D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
04-18 23:20:56.858 25376-25376/com.example.bebo.facebook I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
04-18 23:20:56.858 25376-25376/com.example.bebo.facebook W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 486: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
04-18 23:20:56.858 25376-25376/com.example.bebo.facebook D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
04-18 23:20:57.328 25376-25376/com.example.bebo.facebook D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
04-18 23:20:57.558 25376-25401/com.example.bebo.facebook W/dalvikvm: threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41603c08)
04-18 23:20:57.568 25376-25401/com.example.bebo.facebook E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
04-18 23:20:57.568 25376-25401/com.example.bebo.facebook E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.bebo.facebook, PID: 25376
04-18 23:20:57.568 25376-25401/com.example.bebo.facebook E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-18 23:20:57.568 25376-25401/com.example.bebo.facebook E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.containsKey(ConcurrentHashMap.java:911)
04-18 23:20:57.568 25376-25401/com.example.bebo.facebook E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.facebook.internal.Utility.queryAppSettings(Utility.java:822)
04-18 23:20:57.568 25376-25401/com.example.bebo.facebook E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$1.run(LoginButton.java:489)
04-18 23:20:57.568 25376-25401/com.example.bebo.facebook E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
04-18 23:20:57.568 25376-25401/com.example.bebo.facebook E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
04-18 23:20:57.568 25376-25401/com.example.bebo.facebook E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error "Unfortunately App has stopped working" occurs whenever your code runs into some `RuntimeException` and most of the time it is `NullPointerException`, as in your case too (you can notice the `NullPointerException` in the logcat! ). Being new in android programming, it occurs very often. As you told that you took help from some tutorial, my guess is that you just copied the code into your project and then tried to run. (Correct me if I am wrong! ;) ). If you did that, then undo that first, then try to understand the code first. After you get the feeling that you grabbed something and now you feel like starting, start by copying small chunks of code and then running it every time you add a new chunk. Like this, you will keep on checking whether that chunk is really working or not, plus you will uplift your confidence. Then at some time you will come across that evil part! Now knowing exactly what is causing the pain, you can treat it well! In nutshell, all I wanna say is that as you move forward, keep on debugging the aggregated code. Best of luck!